# HttpServletRequest.getParameter() truncates the value sent through jQuery.ajax

Tags: java, servlets, gson, truncate, getparameter

I am having an issue when I sent data via POST using jquery.ajax and try to read the value from the HttpServletRequest in java. I am using jdk6 jboss-4.0.3 Struts 1 and for ajax I am using GSON and jquery in the client side

Here is my code : JSP

```
 jQuery.ajax({
      url:'relatorioVolumenNegocio.do?dispatch=changeGraphs',
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      type: "POST",
     data: { values: value },
     success: function(data){
     //do some stuff
     }
 });
```

The JSON value contains the following data:

In the browser:

```
[Object { indicador=0, descripcion="Comércio a retalho de c...l para veículos a motor", importe=65}, Object { indicador=1, descripcion="Fundos de pensões", importe=171}, Object { indicador=2, descripcion="Transportes por condutas (pipelines)", importe=0}, 321 more...]
```

(I know is a bunch of data...) Here I can see all the JSON data perfectly, but in the server  side I get only this:

```
{"graphData":[{"indicador":51,"descripcion":"Comércio de veículos automóveis","importe":974},{"indicador":15,"descripcion":"Actividades imobiliárias por conta própria","importe":967},{"indicador":140,"descripcion":"Consultoria em equipamento informático","importe":924},{"indicador":308,"descripcion":"Horticultura e produtos de viveiro","importe":881},{"indicador":197,"descripcion":"Comércio por grosso de materiais de construção (excepto madeira) e equipamento sanitário","importe":831},{"indicador":180,"descripcion":"Comércio por grosso de minérios e de metais","importe":792},{"indicador":123,"descripcion":"Fabricação de tijolos, telhas e de outros produtos de barro para a construção","importe":790},{"indicador":20,"descripcion":"Comércio a retalho de ferragens, tintas, vidros, equipamento sanitário, ladrilhos e similares","importe":749},{"indicador":311,"descripcion":"Administração pública ? actividades económicas","importe":742},{"indicador":209,"descripcion":"Agentes do comércio por grosso de produtos alimentares, bebidas e tabaco","importe":714},{"indicador":279,"descripcion":"Comércio a retalho de produtos farmacêuticos, médicos, cosméticos e de higiene","importe":712},{"indicador":130,"descripcion":"Actividades de contabilidade, auditoria e consultoria fiscal","importe":557},{"indicador":54,"descripcion":"Restaurantes, n.e.","importe":552},{"indicador":39,"descripcion":"Ensino médio","importe":551},{"indicador":239,"descripcion":"Fabricação de joalharia, ourivesaria e artigos similares","importe":543},{"indicador":136,"descripcion":"Saneamento, higiene pública e actividades similares","importe":526},{"indicador":27,"descripcion":"Edição de livros, brochuras, partituras e similares","importe":513},{"indicador":211,"descripcion":"Fundição de metais ferrosos","importe":513},{"indicador":112,"descripcion":"Actividades de arquitectura, de engenharia e técnicas afins","importe":497},{"indicador":172,"descripcion":"Serração, aplainamento e impregnação da madeira","importe":481},{"indicador":10,"descripcion":"Ensino pré-universitário","importe":449},{"indicador":161,"descripcion":"Actividades de consultoria para os negócios e a gestão","importe":440},{"indicador":93,"descripcion":"Ensino superior","importe":423},{"indicador":57,"descripcion":"Restaurantes com lugares ao balcão (snack bares)","importe":415},{"indicador":106,"descripcion":"Engenharia civil","importe":403},{"indicador":182,"descripcion":"Reciclagem de sucata e de desperdícios metálicos","importe":387},{"indicador":6,"descripcion":"Outras actividades de crédito","importe":384},{"indicador":37,"descripcion":"Outra intermediação financeira, n.e.","importe":369},{"indicador":191,"descripcion":"Administração local","importe":369},{"indicador":81,"descripcion":"Comércio a retalho por outros métodos, não efectuado em estabelecimentos","importe":362},{"indicador":306,"descripcion":"Comércio a retalho de têxteis e de vestuário","importe":361},{"indicador":252,"descripcion":"Outro comércio por grosso de bens de consumo","importe":354},{"indicador":200,"descripcion":"Outras actividades educativas, n.e.","importe":348},{"indicador":82,"descripcion":"Panificação","importe":340},{"indicador":124,"descripcion":"Estabelecimentos hoteleiros sem restaurante, n.e.","importe":330},{"indicador":158,"descripcion":"Outros transportes terrestres regulares de passageiros","importe":322},{"indicador":205,"descripcion":"Formação profissional","importe":320},{"indicador":76,"descripcion":"Educação pré-escolar","importe":311},{"indicador":157,"descripcion":"Outras actividades conexas à informática","importe":300},{"indicador":292,"descripcion":"Actividades de salões de cabeleireiro e institutos de beleza","importe":293},{"indicador":251,"descripcion":"Actividades de saúde humana, n.e.","importe":287},{"indicador":29,"descripcion":"Cafés e pastelarias","importe":261},{"indicador":24,"descripcion":"Cantinas e fornecimento de refeições ao domicílio (catering)","importe":259},{"indicador":8,"descripcion":"Fabricação de artigos de cortiça e de outras obras de madeira, n.e.","importe":251},{"indicador":41,"descripcion":"Outras actividades de diversão e espectáculo, n.e.","importe":248},{"indicador":223,"descripcion":"Comércio por grosso de combustíveis líquidos, sólidos, gasosos e produtos derivados","importe":246},{"indicador":92,"descripcion":"Comércio a retalho de máquinas e de outro material de escritório","importe":242},{"indicador":260,"descripcion":"Comércio a retalho de bebidas","importe":235},{"indicador":208,"descripcion":"Agentes do comércio por grosso de madeira, materiais de construção, mobiliário, artigos para uso doméstico e ferragens","importe":222},{"indicador":312,"descripcion":"PARTICULARES","importe":213.898},{"indicador":18,"descripcion":"Acção social sem alojamento, n.e.","importe":201},{"indicador":174,"descripcion":"Comércio por grosso de outros produtos alimentares","importe":198},{"indicador":160,"descripcion":"Actividades dos agentes transitários, aduaneiros e similares de apoio ao transporte","importe":197},{"indicador":275,"descripcion":"Actividades de protecção civil","importe":197},{"indicador":235,"descripcion":"Manutenção e reparação de veículos automóveis","importe":196},{"indicador":305,"descripcion":"Actividades de prática médica e dentária, sem internamento","importe":182},{"indicador":1,"descripcion":"Fundos de pensões","importe":171},{"indicador":226,"descripcion":"Aluguer de meios de transporte terrestre","importe":163},{"indicador":45,"descripcion":"Comércio a retalho de mobiliário e artigos de iluminação","importe":158},{"indicador":202,"descripcion":"Escolas de condução e pilotagem","importe":158},{"indicador":118,"descripcion":"Abate de gado (produção de carne)","importe":144},{"indicador":144,"descripcion":"Extrac. de petróleo e gás natural","importe":135},{"indicador":288,"descripcion":"Administração pública - actividades de educação","importe":135},{"indicador":317,"descripcion":"Montagem de trabalhos de carpintaria e de caixilharia","importe":134},{"indicador":50,"descripcion":"Comércio a retalho de outros artigos para o lar, n.e.","importe":130},{"indicador":232,"descripcion":"Comércio por grosso de têxteis e vestuário","importe":124},{"indicador":38,"descripcion":"Segurança social \"obrigatória\"","importe":120},{"indicador":59,"descripcion":"Pensões com restaurante","importe":120},{"indicador":257,"descripcion":"Comércio a retalho de peixe, crustáceos e moluscos","importe":119},{"indicador":77,"descripcion":"Ensino básico (1º nível)","importe":114},{"indicador":83,"descripcion":"Pastelaria","importe":111},{"indicador":176,"descripcion":"Comércio por grosso de leite e derivados, ovos, azeite, óleos e gorduras alimentares","importe":107},{"indicador":291,"descripcion":"Viticultura","importe":106},{"indicador":254,"descripcion":"Comércio por grosso de perfumes, produtos de higiene e de produtos farmacêuticos","importe":105},{"indicador":261,"descripcion":"Impressão","importe":102},{"indicador":198,"descripcion":"Comércio por grosso de madeira em bruto e de produtos derivados","importe":95},{"indicador":43,"descripcion":"Actividades dos estabelecimentos de saúde com internamento","importe":92},{"indicador":269,"descripcion":"Comércio a retalho de frutas e de produtos hortícolas","importe":92},{"indicador":255,"descripcion":"Comércio por grosso de artigos de papelaria, livros, revistas e jornais","importe":87},{"indicador":168,"descripcion":"Confecção de outros artigos e acessórios de vestuário, n.e.","importe":85},{"indicador":21,"descripcion":"Fabricação de artigos de plástico, n.e.","importe":84},{"indicador":71,"descripcion":"Actividades de organizações profissionais","importe":80},{"indicador":143,"descripcion":"Outros transportes terrestres ocasionais de passageiros","importe":73},{"indicador":300,"descripcion":"Comércio por grosso de bens intermédios (não agrícolas), n.e., de desperdícios e sucatas","importe":73},{"indicador":207,"descripcion":"Agentes do comércio por grosso misto sem predominância","importe":66.527},{"indicador":304,"descripcion":"Actividades auxiliares de intermediação financeira, n.e.","importe":66},{"indicador":0,"descripcion":"Comércio a retalho de combustível para veículos a motor","importe":65},{"indicador":256,"descripcion":"Fabricação de produtos farmacêuticos e de preparações para uso medicinal","importe":64},{"indicador":272,"descripcion":"Transporte e distribuição de electricidade","importe":58},{"indicador":263,"descripcion":"Actividades de enfermagem","importe":55},{"indicador":296,"descripcion":"Reparação de bens pessoais e domésticos, n.e.","importe":55},{"indicador":242,"descripcion":"Moagem de cereais","importe":54},{"indicador":95,"descripcion":"Comércio a retalho de livros, jornais e artigos de papelaria","importe":53},{"indicador":23,"descripcion":"Silvicultura","importe":52},{"indicador":52,"descripcion":"Comércio a retalho de louças, cutelaria e de outros artigos similares para uso doméstico","importe":52},{"indicador":125,"descripcion":"Pensões sem restaurante","importe":52},{"indicador":55,"descripcion":"Fabricação de cerveja e malte","importe":50},{"indicador":231,"descripcion":"Comércio por grosso de outras máquinas e equipamentos para a indústria, comércio e navegação","importe":49},{"indicador":154,"descripcion":"Pesca em águas interiores","importe":48},{"indicador":270,"descripcion":"Comércio a retalho de carne e de produtos à base de carne","importe":47},{"indicador":73,"descripcion":"Tratamento e revestimento de metais; actividades de mecânica geral","importe":46},{"indicador":253,"descripcion":"Outras actividades recreativas, n.e.","importe":46},{"indicador":12,"descripcion":"Ensino básico (3º nível)","importe":45},{"indicador":32,"descripcion":"Cervejarias e bares","importe":45},{"indicador":47,"descripcion":"Reconstrução de pneus","importe":45},{"indicador":30,"descripcion":"Edição de jornais, revistas e outras publicações periódicas","importe":44},{"indicador":78,"descripcion":"...
```

Look at he end. Ends with ... and that throws this exception

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 6278
```

I think there is an issue with the request size, but I don't know how to change. 
I really appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you look at the data in server side ? Directly in request ? How ? Did you spy what the browser really sent ?

Comment: How do you know the `...` is actually in the data and not just the way it is displayed by whatever means you used to display it?  There should not be a limit that small on POST data.  You will have to analyze the actual network traffic using Wireshark to see what is actually happening.

Comment: I think its because you're mixing GET and POST. Since you're using POST take off `?dispatch=changeGraphs` from the URL and include that in the `data` section.

Comment: developerwjk thanks! thanks all of you for your tips.